# Node Async SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I keep getting this error in my express app:

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/egyplaces/routes/places.js:121
    Place.findById(req.params.id, async function(err,  place){
                                  ^^^^^
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

I've triple checked and can't find any missing ")" anywhere. Here's the code for the whole route.

```
router.put("/places/:id", middleware.checkPlaceOwnership, upload.single("image"), function(req, res) {
    Place.findById(req.params.id, async function(err, place){
        if(err) {
            req.flash("error", "Place not found.");
            res.redirect("/places");
        } else {
            if(req.file) {
                try {
                    await cloudinary.v2.uploader.destroy(place.imageId);
                    var result = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.file.path);
                    place.imageId = result.public_id;
                    place.image = result.secure_url;
                } catch(err) {
                    req.flash("error", err.message);
                    return res.redirect("back");    
                }
            }
            place.name = req.body.place.name;
            place.address = req.body.place.address;
            place.description = req.body.place.description;
            place.save();
            req.flash("success", "Successfully updated!");
            res.redirect("/places/" + req.params.id);
        }
    });  
});
```

Comment: What happens if you make the function non-anonymous, i.e. define it somewhere else and call it by its name while calling the `findById` function?

Comment: Are you using using a node version above 7.6.0? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Node.js version < 7.6, it don't support `async/await`

If you want use `async/await` please update your Node.js.

Or you can use `.then` of that promise (don't need `async/await`).

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting mad. I have node version v13.14.0 and I'm getting this error. I searched in all pages possible and I didn't find any solution. Yesterday, it was working. The only thing I changed was to install capacitor (https://capacitorjs.com/). But just after I have installed it, I did a `npm start` and it still worked!

After some tries, I managed to solve it. It was happening because the module capacitor installed other version of electronjs (I don't know why this error wasn't thrown immediately after the instalation of capacitor) and when I upgrade the package (electronjs) it worked. Seem this error is not only node dependenced.